# Basic c++ program refuses to execute

Tags: c++

I have been using c++ last year and it worked just fine. Not something fancy but basic math programs and I didn't find any problem with compiling it.
Today, tried a simple hello world program and the iostream library appears red in VSC and I followed all the answers here to no avail!
the error is

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:64:10: fatal error: 
      'sys/_pthread/_pthread_condattr_t.h' file not found
#include <sys/_pthread/_pthread_condattr_t.h>
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: This is not a standard C++ header. It must some non-standard header file that's specific to your compiler and/or operating system. And since "last year" that has changed. Or your compiler installation became corrupted, for some unknown reason.

Comment: Can you show the command line that Visual Studio Code is attempting to execute.  If you use XCode, do you have the same error?

Comment: What did you change? I assume that you changed your usual way of building and executing. You did not by chance change your environment from something else to VSC?

Comment: The first thing you should check if the file `_pthread_condattr_t.h` exists in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_pthread/`. That file comes as part of the command-line tools installed. If it is there then something with compiler settings and used compiler might be wrong. Some additional include paths in the wrong order or a wrong compiler.

Answer (score -1):

If you using threads in your program
compile with g++:

```
g++ -o a.out *.cpp -pthread
```